# Pytorch: Efficiently compute unbiased estimator of mean to the power of four

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, torch

Let w, x, y, z be torch tensors of shape (m, n) and we wish to compute the following unbiased estimator row-wise efficiently (without for loops), where I want to compute for every row 1, ..., m:

[image: formula]

In case of only the unbiased estimator of the square of means, i.e., for :

[image: formula]

this is possible, e.g., using torch.einsum:

```
batch_outer = torch.einsum('bi, bj -> bij', x, y) 
zero_diag = 1-torch.eye(batch_outer.shape[1])
return (batch_outer * zero_diag).sum(dim=2).sum(dim=1) / (n * (n-1))
```

However, for the case to the power of four this is not so easy doable, mostly because these are not squared tensors and in particular, because the zeroing out of the diagonals becomes very tedious.

My questions:

1.) How can this be implemented efficiently ommitting any for loops?

2.) Which time and memory complexity would that solution have in big O notation?

3.) Can this solution also be used to do it with four 3D tensors of shape (m, k, n), where again we only want to do the computations along the axes of length n (dim=2)?

4.) If I want to do it in log-space for numerical stability, i.e., to use logsumexp for summations and sums for multiplications (because log(xy)= log(x)+log(y)), any solution with einsum wouldnt work anymore. How could that computation then be done in log space?

Comment: Isn't it possible to refactor that quadruple summation ? Since the dimensions of all `w,x,y,z` are equal to `n`, we can write it as individual sums, i.e. `sum(w)*sum(x)*sum(y)*sum(z)` ? No? Probably in this sum also contains the sums where `i==j==k==l` but I am sure it can be taken care of.

Comment: @guest1 The bounty will expire soon and nobody even commented my answer! Are you  still interested? did it work to you? I think is fair at least a comment saying if it worked or not after expending some time on this.

Answer (score 0):

1 This implementation seems to work if I didn't make mess with the diagonal dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
import torch as th

x = np.array([1,4,5,3])
y = np.array([5,2,4,5])[np.newaxis]
z = np.array([5,7,4,5])[np.newaxis][np.newaxis]
w = np.array([3,9,5,1])[np.newaxis][np.newaxis][np.newaxis]

xth = th.Tensor(x)
yth = th.Tensor(y)
zth = th.Tensor(z)
wth = th.Tensor(w)

tensor = xth*th.transpose(yth, 0, 1)*th.transpose(zth,0,2)*th.transpose(wth,0,3)
diag = th.diagonal(tensor, dim1 = -2, dim2 = -1)
result = th.sum(tensor) - th.sum(diag)
result /= np.math.factorial(len(x))
print(result)
```

2. The order is between `O(n^2.37..) - O(n^3)`, depending on the pytorch implementation of the matrix multiplication.
3. I don't see why not, just choose properly the dimensions to transpose and take the diagonal.
4. I don't see why would this solution won't work in a log-space.

pd: my knowledge in pytorch is quite limited, but I'm sure you can define `x,y,z,w` in a more elegant way.